# Moving large dataset across django databases

Tags: python, django, database, dataset, migration

What's the best way to move large dataset from one django database to another?

I would like to do this at high level (in django) and not at the database level. All the existing tools that I know of (dumpdata/loaddata, serializer class, django-extensions) are in memory so it doesn't handle large datasets.

Comment: starred and +1'd. I think this is interesting!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this post very useful - [Migrating Django from MySQL to PostgreSQL the Easy Way](http://www.ofbrooklyn.com/2010/07/18/migrating-django-mysql-postgresql-easy-way/).

Comment: This article was good--provides an answer to a problem I was having with a memoryerror during load/dumpdata with a largish database.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with several apps/databases, so wrote this script, which is a fork of django's dumpdata, but dumps data in chunks to avoid MemoryError

Script is available at https://github.com/fastinetserver/django-dumpdata-chunks

Example usage:

1) Dump data into many files:

```
mkdir some-folder

./manage.py dumpdata_chunks your-app-name
--output-folder=./some-folder --max-records-per-chunk=100000
```

2) Load data from the folder:

```
find ./some-folder | egrep -o "([0-9]+_[0-9]+)" | xargs ./manage.py loaddata
```